# Class attribute [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] equivalent in ServiceStack

Tags: c#-4.0, servicestack, custom-attributes, json.net, servicestack-text

Is there [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] equivalent attribute class in ServiceStack? This is a Newtonsoft for converting enum to string?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the following configuration option:

```
ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.TreatEnumAsInteger = true;
```

By default your enums will be serialized as strings. You need to specify true to override this.

See the unit tests at [tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/EnumTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/EnumTests.cs?source=cc) for more information.